# Laravel not displaying uploaded pngs but displays jpgs

Tags: laravel, image

Here is my code that uploads a file to the server from a form

```
if(isset($request->fileupond)&&($request->fileupond!=null)){
           $name=md5(microtime(true).uniqid()).'.'.$request->fileupond->getClientOriginalExtension();
           $request->fileupond->storeAs('public/logos',$name);
} else {
    $name="";
}
```

When I upload a `jpg` using html:

`<img src="{{ url('/storage/logos/'.$prop->avatar) }}" class="profiel-upload-step">`

it works fine. however, when i use a `png` it displays a missing image.

Comment: whats the file extension in the uploaded png-s? `.png` or `.PNG`?? from my experience `.PNG` did not work. had to make it `.png`.

Comment: Open `storage/logos` and visually confirm how the files are getting saved as.